# Post to facebook wall from iOS app which is build using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, cordova

I have an app build using Phonegap, so total HTML and Java Scripts thats all I have.
I can check using two lines of objective C code that facebook is installed on perticular device or not within my app.
I want to have a facebook share button in my app,
 by clicking on which will open facebook app from my app and will post some data on user's wall which I can pass over this app call.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [FacebookConnect](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/FacebookConnect) Plugin for Phonegap, it works for iOS and Android.

Please download [sample](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect) application and try in the following snippet in you code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plugin.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <div id="plugindemo">
                <h3>FacebookConnect Plugin</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="plugin.login();">login()</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="plugin.requestWithGraphPath();">requestWithGraphPath()</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="plugin.dialog();">dialog()</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="plugin.logout();">logout()</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/FacebookConnect.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```